# Counting average profit of conditional order

Tags: oracle

I have the following table

```
Order_lines(`Order line`,`order number`,`price`,`sale`,`profit`,`order item`)
```

Some order numbers have more than one item.

I need to calculate the average profit for the orders that have more than 5 line items.

I put my query like this:

```
select ROUND(profit/count(item),0) Average Profit
from order_lines;
having count(item)>5;
```

But it doesn't work. can anyone please help me with this? Thank you so much!!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, SQL has a bit of a procedural component to it -- allowing you to break down a problem into multiple, smaller steps.

Try this two-step approach:

```
SELECT AVG (profit)
FROM   (SELECT SUM (profit) profit
        FROM   order_lines
        GROUP BY order_number
        HAVING COUNT (*) > 5);
```

First, we get a list of orders having >5 lines and the profit on each, then we average those profits.

Comment: My SQL Developer stills says ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended with your entry, do you think I need to clarify more with the AVG command?

Comment: It runs on my system.  Post the _exact_ SQL you are running that gives the error.  Also, note, you need to group by order_number, not order_line.  Sorry for that.  I've corrected in my answer.

Comment: Yes it works now thanks to your update! However, my instructor needs the average profit for each order with more than 5 lines item and the answer should be 3 rows but I only get 1 row with your help. How can I fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: There are 3 orders with more than 5 line items in the table and I need a query to find the average profit of each order.

Comment: Your instructor?  Argh..  Do your own homework, please.  I'll give you a last hint: that's an easier question than what you first posted and can be done in one "step".